# Hide keyboard on enter/next press with react-native-pell-rich-editor

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm in need of hide the keyboard when the user submit or press the enter/next key of the keyboard.
Here's the code i'm using to the RichEditor TextInput.

```js
<RichEditor
    ref={rf => this.richText = rf}
    initialContentHTML={this.state.PostDescription}
    style={{
      // minHeight:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 30 : 40,
      // maxHeight:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100: 40,
      height:'100%',
      backgroundColor:'white',
      flex: 1,justifyContent:'center',
      minWidth:'100%',width:'100%'
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/cactis/ct-ui-kit/blob/472a3f3eb774651aeef7578bced9c34994f86c30/src/Components/Editor/Tags/P1.js) code as example, you can make the RichEditor blur using:

```
this.richText.blurContentEditor();
```

But, there's no `OnSubmit` function (Or at least i dont found it on my search), as it's just a `webview` of [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) and not a TextInput.

You can use [react-native-webview-quilljs](https://github.com/reggie3/react-native-webview-quilljs) as they have `ON_KEY_PRESS` event and get the Enter key press.

Comment: Does react-native-webview-quilljs contains method like onchangetext or onsubmit like or hide keyboard.

Comment: is there a way to hide keybord only but not blur editor.because when keyboard hide editor focus not working. i want to focus editor but hide keyboard only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react-native-pell-rich-editor?

If yes, you can use the below code to dismiss the keyboard.

```
this.richText.current.dismissKeyboard()
```